# Verification an inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

This problem arose when I was reading the proof of Lemma $A.1$ of [Koenker and Portnoy ($1988$)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2288796?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)'s paper *L-Estimation for Linear Models*.

For better exposition, I reformulated the original statement as follows:

> Given 
>   $$M(u) = pe^{u(1 - p)} + (1 - p)e^{-up},$$
>   where $p \in (0, 1)$, $u \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that
>   $$M(u) \leq 1 + 2pu^2e^{|u|}.$$

The paper presented this inequality without any explanation, while to me it looks not that trivial. Any hints?

Comment: Why do you need the $\log$'s, by the way? (they are just there "for show")

Comment: Of course, $\log$ can be removed, the $\log$ is involved because in the paper it is like that.

Comment: Have you tried to study the function $$f(u) = p e^{u(1-p)} + (1-p)e^{-up} - (1+2pu^2e^{\lvert u\rvert})$$ (i.e., differentiating, etc.)? This is probably by far not the most elegant, but there is a non-zero chance it may work.

Comment: I tried, but it is inconclusive to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed it by integrating the derivative. Since $M(0) = 1$,

$$M(u)-1 = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial M(tu)}{\partial t} \ dt = p(1-p)u \int_0^1 \left(e^{(1-p)ut}-e^{-put} \right) \ dt.$$

Note that:

$$\int_0^1 \left(e^{(1-p)ut}-e^{-put} \right) \ dt = \int_0^1 \left(e^{(1-p)ut}-1\right) + \left(1-e^{-put} \right) \ dt.$$

Since $e^x-1 \leq xe^x$ (and equivalently $1-e^{-x}\leq x$) for all $x$, for non-negative $u$, we get:

$$\int_0^1 \left(e^{(1-p)ut}-e^{-put} \right) \ dt \leq \int_0^1 (1-p)ut e^{(1-p)ut}+put \ dt \leq \frac{ue^{|u|}}{2}.$$

Similarly, for non-positive $u$, we get:

$$\int_0^1 \left(e^{(1-p)ut}-e^{-put} \right) \ dt \geq \int_0^1 (1-p)ut+put e^{-put} \ dt \geq \frac{ue^{|u|}}{2}.$$

In all cases,

$$M(u) \leq 1+\frac{pu^2}{2}e^{|u|}.$$

(with all the potential sign errors, it might be a good idea to check my computations)

Comment: In general looks very promising. Could you explain more on how to get $$\int_0^1 (1-p)ut e^{(1-p)ut}+put \ dt \leq \frac{ue^{|u|}}{2}$$? It doesn't look very straightforward.

Comment: @Solitary: in this case, everything is positive. A upper bound for $(1-p)tue^{(1-p)ut}$ is $(1-p)tue^{|u|}$, and a upper bound for $ptu$ is also $ptue^{|u|}$.

Comment: How nice! Thank you very much!